# generate CPU load in Java

Tags: java, encryption, load, cpu

I am conducting some throughput testing. My application has to

1. read from JMS
2. do some processing
3. write to JMS

My goal here is to simulate #2, 'some processing'. That is, introduce a delay and occupy the CPU for a given time (e.g. 500ms) before forwarding the event.

The naive approach would be to `Thread.sleep(500)`. This would introduce the right delay in execution, but would not exercise the CPU.

Calculating Fibonacci numbers is one option.
**Has anyone used any interesting techniques just to keep CPU(s) busy for a given time?**

Ideal characteristics would be:

- Performs a variety of instructions, rather than (for example) just spinning on a loop
- Not something the HotSpot VM is going to optimise away to nothing
- Has an easy way to adjust the processing period up or down (time to complete will clearly vary given the hardware)

Comment: Can you further explain why utilizing the CPU is necessary but simply sleeping with Thread.sleep() isn't suitable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "exercise the CPU" and why exactly you would need to do that. Could you please elaborate a bit more? What exactly are you testing here? From what I can see it is either the "some processing", read/write JMS or something that sends data to this thing.Thanks.

Comment: > sleep isn't suitable
I need the JMS operations to happen under realistic CPU conditions. An idle CPU might give me falsely high JMS performance; I need the CPU to be 'realistically' busy so my JMS measurement is good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encrypt a string (in a loop) by calling Cipher.update().  Encryption algorithms are by definition very difficult to optimize.  The only problem is that there is some non-trivial setup you need to perform.  I'm marking this answer as community wiki, so that somebody who's written it recently can fill it in.

Answer (score 22):

You could try something simple like

```
private static void spin(int milliseconds) {
    long sleepTime = milliseconds*1000000L; // convert to nanoseconds
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) < sleepTime) {}
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUM_TESTS = 1000;
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
        spin(500);
    }
    System.out.println("Took " + (System.nanoTime()-start)/1000000 +
        "ms (expected " + (NUM_TESTS*500) + ")");
}
```

My output:

```
$ java SpinTest
Took 500023ms (expected 500000)
```

So the loop didn't get optimized away (and yeah, I spiked my CPU to 100% for eight minutes just to test this :)).

Comment: This will work until the next version of HotSpot optimizes it away...

Comment: This isn't working on multiple threads. I created 50 threads and made each thread spin for 10 seconds using the above code. But the program still finished in 11 seconds. My machine as only 12 logical cores.

I do see the CPU getting spiked up to 100% in the task manager.

Comment: @toolforger Why would the loop be optimized away? The loop condition depends on calling System.nanoTime(), which from static code perspective, might as well be a Random#nextLong, and have side-effects. I suspect the JVM doesn't optimize side-effects away, nor loops for which the iteration count is unknown - that would break software. It could optimize the loop away, had the loop, for example, been incrementing a number for a fixed number of iterations, and then the number to be printed.

Comment: @Priyshrm The logical core count doesn't indicate how many threads can do their work. Your OS is likely running several thousand threads even when idling. My OS is configured to allow a max of 255k threads. What the core count affects, is how many of those threads run truly *parallel* to each other. Above that, and the CPU is context-switching, mixing execution of pieces of all scheduled threads one by one. The 1 second above 10 seconds expected is that thread switching. Also, see "atomic" (like atom), which is about non-splittable pieces of execution.

Comment: @iwat0qs Hmm... as long as the time is printed, the result is actually used and it cannot be optimized away. Maybe the answer originally didn't use the result, maybe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 5):

Create a very large collection of random objects and then alternate calls to `Collections.shuffle()` and `Collections.sort()`.

I used Jakarta Commons Lang to generate random strings for the purposes of shuffling/sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a matrix and do a couple of matrix manipulations.

You can tune that pretty easily by varying the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another stuff you can use, maybe :

```
        long start  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long count = 0l;
        for(long x=0;x<Integer.MAX_VALUE ;x++){
            count+=1;
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end-start +" ms");
```